# Processing JSON using rjson

Tags: json, r, rjson

I'm trying to process some data in JSON format. `rjson::fromJSON` imports the data successfully and places it into a quite unwieldy list.

```
library(rjson)
y <- fromJSON(file="http://api.lmiforall.org.uk/api/v1/wf/predict/breakdown/region?soc=6145&minYear=2014&maxYear=2020")
str(y)
List of 3
 $ soc                : num 6145
 $ breakdown          : chr "region"
 $ predictedEmployment:List of 7
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ year     : num 2014
  .. ..$ breakdown:List of 12
  .. .. ..$ :List of 3
  .. .. .. ..$ code      : num 1
  .. .. .. ..$ name      : chr "London"
  .. .. .. ..$ employment: num 74910
  .. .. ..$ :List of 3
  .. .. .. ..$ code      : num 7
  .. .. .. ..$ name      : chr "Yorkshire and the Humber"
  .. .. .. ..$ employment: num 61132
  ...
```

However, as this is essentially tabular data, I would like it in a succinct `data.frame`. After much trial and error I have the result:

```
y.p <- do.call(rbind,lapply(y[[3]], function(p) cbind(p$year,do.call(rbind,lapply(p$breakdown, function(q) data.frame(q$name,q$employment,stringsAsFactors=F))))))
head(y.p)
  p$year                   q.name q.employment
1   2014                   London     74909.59
2   2014 Yorkshire and the Humber     61131.62
3   2014     South West (England)     65833.57
4   2014                    Wales     33002.64
5   2014  West Midlands (England)     68695.34
6   2014     South East (England)     98407.36
```

But the command seems overly fiddly and complex. Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure it is simpler, but the result is more complete and I think is easier to read. My idea using `Map` is, for each couple (year,breakdown), aggregate breakdown data into single table and then combine it with year.

```
dat <- y[[3]]
res <- Map(function(x,y)data.frame(year=y,
                                   do.call(rbind,lapply(x,as.data.frame))),
        lapply(dat,'[[','breakdown'),
        lapply(dat,'[[','year'))
## transform the list to a big data.frame
do.call(rbind,res)
   year code                     name employment
1  2014    1                   London   74909.59
2  2014    7 Yorkshire and the Humber   61131.62
3  2014    4     South West (England)   65833.57
4  2014   10                    Wales   33002.64
5  2014    5  West Midlands (England)   68695.34
6  2014    2     South East (England)   98407.36
```

Comment: I've accepted this answer, as it is easier to read what is going on.

Comment: When I run this, e.g., `lapply(dat, "[[", "breakdown")` with `dat = y` I get `Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : subscript out of bounds` ??

Comment: @MartinMorgan good catch.I edit my answer. I forget to mention that `dat <- y[[3]]`

Comment: @agstudy Thanks for your excellent answer!  May I ask, I have never seen lapply used in the way you have here.  Can you explain what's happening?  I am used to lapply being of the form:  lapply(<object>, <function>), but you seem to be pulling out some portion of the object.  How does this work?  The object, dat, does not even have 'breakdown' or 'year' at their highest level.  I cannot seem to find anything within the documentation to explain this use case.  Thanks so much!!

Comment: @MikeWilliamson you can see `?lapply` is `lapply(X, FUN, ...)` where `...`  are `optional arguments to FUN`. So here my FUN is `[[` to  which I give column name (breakdown or year) as optional argument.

Comment: @agstudy Thanks for your reply!  Yes, I understand that you can send a function to lapply.  I just don't understand how `[[` is captured as a function.  For instance, I couldn't say `[[(dat, 'breakdown')` and expect any response.  I see what it's doing:  it's grabbing the subgroup within dat called 'breakdown'.  In effect, it's doing `dat$breakdown`, or `dat[["breakdown"]]`.  But I've never seen this usage and still don't quite get how / why it works.

Answer (score 5):

Here I recover the geometry of the list

```
ni <- seq_along(y[[3]])
nj <- seq_along(y[[c(3, 1, 2)]])
nij <- as.matrix(expand.grid(3, ni=ni, 2, nj=nj))
```

then extract the relevant variable information using the rows of `nij` as an index into the nested list

```
data <- apply(nij, 1, function(ij) y[[ij]])
year <- apply(cbind(nij[,1:2], 1), 1, function(ij) y[[ij]])
```

and make it into a more friendly structure

```
> data.frame(year, do.call(rbind, data))
   year code                     name employment
1  2014    1                   London   74909.59
2  2015    5  West Midlands (England)   69132.34
3  2016   12         Northern Ireland   24313.94
4  2017    5  West Midlands (England)    71723.4
5  2018    9     North East (England)   27199.99
6  2019    4     South West (England)   71219.51
```

Comment: Hai @agstudy I tried to implement this method to our case, but I am still failed, this is my case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27227208/how-to-get-nested-value-rjson , I hope any someone can help me