# Replace NA values with value from another column in same dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to replace NA in a particular column with values from another column in same dataframe

DF1:

```
Item    From    Price    Discount    NewPrice
 A     Delhi    100        .10         110
 A     Mumbai   200        .10         120
 A     Pune     150         NA          NA
 A     Nagpur   200        .10          NA
```

I would like to replace NA in NewPrice with the values in column Price

I have referred this but it is not helping [Replace empty values with value from other column in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181723/replace-empty-values-with-value-from-other-column-in-a-dataframe)

Have tried below one but not working

```
df$NewPrice <- ifelse(df$NewPrice == "", df$Price, df$NewPrice)
```

Comment: Try `df$NewPrice <- ifelse(is.na(df$NewPrice), df$Price, df$NewPrice)` and see if that works

Comment: In your linked post, the empty value is an empty string `""`, in your case it is `NA`, so we need to check for `is.na` as Andrew showed in above comment.

Comment: It worked guys
Thanks @Andrew Baxter &zx8754

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try with standard subsetting:

```
#subset the NAs of new price with the ones from price
df$NewPrice[is.na(df$NewPrice)] <- df$Price[is.na(df$NewPrice)]
```

Out:

```
df
#  Item   From Price Discount NewPrice
#1    A  Delhi   100      0.1      110
#2    A Mumbai   200      0.1      120
#3    A   Pune   150       NA      150
#4    A Nagpur   200      0.1      200
```

Answer (score 2):

tidyverse solution:

```
df %>% mutate(NewPrice=coalesce(NewPrice, Price))
```